# Angularjs ns-style change via Controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, ng-style

I am trying to change background color of div. Mine html code is below:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color': backgroundImageInfo}">
    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileThatChangeBackground(this)" />
</div>
```

Mine js code inside controller:

```
$scope.backgroundImageInfo='red';
$scope.fileThatChangeBackground = function() {
    alert($scope.backgroundImageInfo);
    $scope.backgroundImageInfo='blue';
};
```

First line of controller change background color to red. When i am set file to input alert show 'red' and did not change background color to blue. When i change file of input(fire function) alert show 'blue' and again did not change background color. Why ng-style dont change color when i change value from function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling the `fileThatChangeBackground` function from outside Angular, you will need to do `$scope.$apply` if you want this to work. Like this:

```
angular.module('testApp',[])
.controller('testCtrllr', function($scope){
    $scope.backgroundImageInfo='red';    
    $scope.fileThatChangeBackground = function(scope) {                    
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.backgroundImageInfo='blue';
        });
    };
});
```

### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zxwye5oa/1/)

Comment: @GoncharDenys no problem, any time!